# Any way to add a decorative border around a chrome tab using css?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

[image]

Sorry if my question is silly; I am a total amateur when it comes to css.

I wanted to make a chrome extension that would allow the user to add a custom decorative border around chrome tabs like the image attached.

At first I thought that it might not be possible, but I encountered an extension called browser pets which creates a little animal which walks across your screen. From this I deduce that putting images on top of a chrome browser is not impossible?

Thank you for taking the time to read this, and I'd love if someone knows the answer.

Comment: I think it is not possible to use CSS to add a border around a Chrome tab. extensions can use the `chrome.tabs` API to modify the properties of a tab.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! Would you be able to guess what techniques the developers for browser pets used to generate a little moving png on screen? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browser-pets/mhgallfjacflgalnbpcpmnfibodgbdkc

Comment: `chrome.extension.getViews` method and the `window.requestAnimationFrame` function to create the animation of the pet moving across the screen.

Comment: also you can use the `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` properties to get the size of the browser window, and use this information to position the image or other content you desired.